# Program halts while sending byte to USB-to-Prallel (D-Sub 25pins) port

Tags: c

I have an USB to 25-pin parallel port cable. I connected it to laptop and get a port at /dev/usb/lp0, then I connect pin1/pin25 of parallel port with +/- LED it lights.
Now I move +pin of LED to pin 2 of parallel port, and try to send byte to port , it should light up but it doesn't. following is my c code in linux.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/io.h>      
void main(void)
{
int port=0x378;
outb(0xff,port);
outb(0x01,port+2);
sleep(1);
outb(0x00,port+2);
printf("‌​End");
}
```

this is my complete program, I also checked it with port=0x3bc but did not work. Even I checked strobe pin 1 by connecting + of LED, it alsways lights but does not go low. May be there is problem with port address.

for /dev/usb/lp0 I also used command line command like $echo $'\xFF' > /dev/usb/lp0 I observed that it does something but does not light up the LED. When I connect LED with pin2 and 25 as + and -. I can see a very little light in side the LED in the beginning but when I run above command that very tiny light disappears but LED does not glow high like it does when I connect it with strobe pin. Also I can only execute above command only two times. Third and later times I thing command does not work while it seems halted.
Can any one help why it halts or how can I get LED switch on/off on data pins? Thanks

Comment: Platform? Most modern OSes deny direct port access. Happened to me on WinXP, had to install a driver **or** use DOS to program the parallel port.

Comment: You can't just write to ports from a userland program like that. You are probably getting "invalid instruction" exception.

Comment: Not only that but it's a USB device... it wouldn't be mapped to the legacy LP port addresses even if it weren't for the memory protection.